# iOS 5 Maintain variables and state in an application?

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am new to iOS 5 programming so I'm sure that these are basic questions for the experienced folks.

1. I have a log in form that creates a unique session string. How can I maintain string in a way that it will be usable on all view controllers throughout the application just for that session?
2. How can I store a series of strings (maybe 1 or 2 of them) so that they will be available to the application on subsequent application loads? In other words, how can I maintain a default string that can be used throughout the lifetime of the application on any given device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this can be stored on the Application Delegate (which is accessible like below from anywhere within your application:

YourAppDelegate.h

```
- (NSString *)uniqueSessionString;
```

View Controller:

```
NSString *uniqueString = [(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] uniqueSessionString];
```

Second, to save this information look at NSUserDefaults.  This information will persist even after the application closes.  Here is a tutorial on using it here:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/

If you need to maintain this string for all of a user's devices, then you need to look at the NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore (part of iCloud).  You also can use both of these methods together.  See this SO question:

[How to use NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore and NSUserDefaults together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070253/how-to-use-nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore-and-nsuserdefaults-together)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the right track for the values in the AppDelegate. I hate to be dense, but I can see how to read the value, but how do I set this value?

Comment: If you set it as a property on the app delegate than you can just call the setter:  [(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] setUniqueSessionString:newValue];