# Is it safe to rely on NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore for storing essential data?

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud, nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore

I learned that `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore` is always available, also when [no iCloud account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174855/251760) is set up. This makes me believe I can safely store essential data in it, without keeping a copy in `NSUserDefaults`.

However, in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore_class/index.html), Apple says the following:

> Avoid using this class for data that is essential to your app’s behavior when offline; instead, store such data directly into the local user defaults database.

Do I overlook issues that might arise when not using `NSUserDefaults` (or another offline store) as back-up? Or is Apple being overprotective and is it safe to rely on `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`?

Comment: did you ever receive an answer for this?

Comment: @AndrewDavis Unfortunately not :(

Comment: curious as well. this asks the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070253/how-to-use-nsubiquitouskeyvaluestore-and-nsuserdefaults-together but the answers don't really get at the core question there and here. i think though, the documentation tends to be king so I'm gonna use both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135779/julien) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11174855/251760#comment41732956_11174855) the following about this question:

> What this means is that you should not rely on this store to be your local truth but more of a simple sync communication channel between your devices.